# Trying to configure MAMP for Magento

Tags: magento, terminal, composer-php, macos-big-sur

I'm working to install Magento 2 on my Mac so I can develop with JetBrains PhpStorm and exchange with my company's server.

I've got MAMP installed and but in working to install Magento 2.3.5-p1, I needs some php extensions set and I'm not certain how to do this.

I need intl, ext-zip and possibly others on. This is what I'm seeing:

composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.3.5-p1
Creating a "magento/project-community-edition=2.3.5-p1" project at "./project-community-edition"
Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.3.5-p1)

- Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.3.5-p1): Extracting archive
  Created project in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project-community-edition
  Loading composer repositories with package information
  Updating dependencies
  Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.5-p1].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.3.5-p1 requires ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
Problem 2
- Root composer.json requires dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer ^0.5.0 -> satisfiable by dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer[v0.5.0].
- dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.0.0] but it does not match the constraint.
Problem 3
- magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[2.6.4, ..., 2.6.6] require php-webdriver/webdriver ^1.8.0 -> satisfiable by php-webdriver/webdriver[1.8.0, ..., 1.10.0].
- php-webdriver/webdriver[1.8.0, ..., 1.10.0] require ext-zip * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's zip extension.
- Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ~2.6.4 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.6.6].

You are using Composer 2, which some of your plugins seem to be incompatible with. Make sure you update your plugins or report a plugin-issue to ask them to support Composer 2.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve that problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Before you start messing around with MAMP's PHP files you might consider the fact that you are trying to install a version of Magento 2 that is lower than 2.4.2 while using a Composer 2.x installation. I'm pretty sure Magento doesn't support Composer 2.x until [2.4.2 was released](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-2.html#platform-enhancements).

Comment: Is there a way to install 2.3.5p1 on MAMP, or - because of the Composer version (I wasn't aware of this limitation) - do I have to go to 2.4.2? My current site is 2.3.5p1, although we're looking to go to 2.4.2 sometime later this year. Both to remain current, and because of the speed that ElasticSearch provides.....

Comment: OK, back on this, after dropping in frustration. But back to more frustration. I tried Homebrew - php wouldn't initialize. Back to MAMP. While MAMP shows a valid PHP 7.4, when II try to do a composer install of Magento 2.4.2-p1 in the document root, I get a fail on lack of intl extension in php. I tried installing PECL to install intl. That fails on phpize. I'm not sure how to get Magento installed at this point on my Mac and not sure why this is so hard. Since MAMP shows working php 7.4, is it PATH to the right php? Any help would be greatly appreciated!